# Scanf function will not loop through my while loop

Tags: c

```
    k = 0;
    while (k == 0){
        printf ("enter a value between 0 - 80\n");
        scanf ("%d", &coldest);

        if(coldest <= 80 && coldest >= 0){
            k = 1;
        }
        else 
            k = 0;
    }
    printf ("this number ---->%d<-----\n", coldest);
```

This is what I wrote and when you put in anything outside of the parameter 0-80 it's suppose to loop and ask the user again, but I'm having a problem where it will skip the `scanf` and just keep popping the `printf`.

Edit: ≤ to <= and ≥ to >=
-Edit2: 80 <= coldest to coldest <= 80

Comment: `80 <= coldest && coldest >=0` --> `coldest>=80`

Comment: `80 ≤ coldest && coldest ≥ 0` I would be surprised if this compiled.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry that's what I put in my actual code, thanks ! But the problem is still there

Comment: It will only pass for numbers greater than 80. You got to fix the condition

Comment: Now you've mutilated the "if" condition to be a syntax error...

Comment: You probably want to learn that debugging yourself it an essential part of programming. You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also using a `do` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition tests

```
is coldest >= 80
AND
is coldest >= 0
```

Can you spot the error now?

In addition, not testing the return value from `scanf` is **always a bug**.

Comment: So I switched the if statements to (coldest <= 80 && coldest >= 0) and if I enter any value outside of the range it will loop the print statement without along the user again

Comment: @MattHuynh And you would find out about the reason why if you heeded my advice in the sentence starting with "In addition".

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `if` condition as

```
if(coldest <= 80 && coldest >= 0)
```

if above condition is true means entered value is  within the specified range..

```
        int main() {
        int coldest = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while (1){ /* while(1) so that until input is not correct keep on ask */

                printf ("enter a value between 0 - 80\n");
                scanf ("%d", &coldest);

                /* if this condition is true means no need to ask user again for input so use break to come out from loop */
                if(coldest <= 80 && coldest >= 0) {
                        k = 1;
                        break;
                }
                else { 
                        k = 0;
                        printf ("not in the range [%d]\n", coldest);
                }
        }
        printf ("this number ---->%d<-----\n", coldest); /* once loop fails it prints */
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `if(80 <= coldest && coldest >= 0)`. `if` is executed after checking the conditions. In your code there are two conditions `80 <= coldest` and `coldest >= 0`. They are joined by `&&` operator.

You want to check whether the given input is in the range of 0 to 80. First condition check whether `coldest` is greater or equal to 80 and at that time it also checks whether `coldest` is greater than 0. It arise due to the use of `&&`. You want to check following cases:-

1. `coldest` is greater than 80

   ```
             && or,
   ```
2. `coldest` is less than 0

Just change the condition of `if(80 <= coldest`**&&**`coldest >= 0)` to `if(coldest >= 80`**||**`coldest <= 0)`. There is logical error in your code. Only change **&&** to **||**. Example:-
If `coldest = 90;` than coldest is